# Download files from multiple Transifex projects

Tags: transifex

How do I download all files from multiple Transifex projects so as to make backup of the files without having to use the web interface and making a lot of clicks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that using the transifex-client and its `tx set --auto-remote <project_url>` feature. Once you have setup the project, you can run a `tx pull -a` to download all the translations. Reference: http://docs.transifex.com/developer/client/remote

Comment: So i run the first command one time for each project and download/backup the files with the second command. But what if lets says new files are added or removed from the project how do i check that the config file matches the current state of the project without having to make the config file from scrath ? Like have would a typical download file look like if someone wanted to download all the files.

Comment: The transifex-client doesn't have that capability. So, in that case, you will need to write your own script making use of the Transifex REST API.